# Match regex on the end but ignore a few parts if exists

Tags: regex

Imagine that I have this delimiter that is on the end of the string: `-holyday[part1]`, I want to match only the `-holyday` and ignore if exists `[part1]`. A complete string example: `with my family - holyday[part1]`.

This is what I have right now but I can only make it match with the `[part1]`:

`\-\s?([\w\[\]]+)$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that your content begins with a `-` and what follows is  `[part1]`
Maybe this is what you are looking for:

[`-\s[\w\s]+(?=\[\w+\])`](https://regex101.com/r/PWauHq/1)

**Explanation**

- Match a dash `-`
- Match a whitespace `\s`
- Match a word character or a white space one or more times `[\w\s]+`
- A positive lookahead `(?=`
- That asserts that what follows is one or more word character between brackets `\[\w+\]`
- Close the lookahead `)`

If the pattern for `-` and `[text]` occurs multiple times and you want only the last occurence, you could for example add another negative lookahead `(?!.*\[.*\])`to assert that
no more patterns like `[text]` follow. (text like `part1`)

[`-\s[\w\s]+(?=\[\w+\](?!.*\[.*\]))`](https://regex101.com/r/yoiWES/1/)

Comment: Your regex works like a charm, the problem now is that it won't match if there's no `[` on the end, is it possible to omit that too and match even if there's no `[`?

Comment: @yugosonegi The `[` is part of the pattern. If you omit the `[` and instead have a whitespace for example `-holyday[part1]`, then you could match it like this: [`-\s[\w\s]+(?=[\[ ]\w+\](?!.*[\[ ].*\]))`](https://regex101.com/r/drjxZW/1) If here is no whitespace, then your string looks like this `- holydaypart1]`. What would you match in this case? Is the text `part1` always the same?

Comment: `-holyday[part1]`, I want to match `holyday` even if there's no `[part1]`.
I added an additional `(?` enclosing the `(?=\[\w+\](?!.*\[.*\]))` like this `(?(?=\[\w+\](?!.*\[.*\])))` and it worked, but I don't know if there's a better alternative for that or it's right

Comment: I think in this case `(?` means an if Clause. But with changing conditions I can not say for sure if there is a better alternative.
If you want to match a word after the last hyphen you could use [`- \w+(?!.*-)`](https://regex101.com/r/mukZKL/1), or without the hyphen (that would put your text in the first capturing group) [`- (\w+)(?!.*-)`](https://regex101.com/r/pq1b1J/1)

Comment: Yes, the idea would be that it can match the `-holyday` even if there's no `[part1]` after that, so it would match `-holyday[part1]` as `holyday` and `-holyday` as `holyday` that is why I put the `(?` to check if there's a `[` after the `holyday` cause the regex you posted would match only if it has a `[` after and I wanted that optional. Got it? But I don't know if I did it right using `(?`.

Comment: I think in that case you could go with [`(?<=- )\w+(?!.*-)`](https://regex101.com/r/bohZg9/1) which uses a positive lookbehind to check if what precedes is a dash and a whitespace. In case of multiple occasions, it matches the last one.

Comment: You are a regex god, holly crap. <3

Answer (score 1):

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group

`(\-\s?\w+)(?:\[part1\])$` does what you want ([example 1](https://regex101.com/r/QzqwQG/1))

and this regex removes everything after `[` (inclusive):

`(\-[^\[]+).*` ([example 2](https://regex101.com/r/QzqwQG/3))

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that I want to get what is before the `[` and ignore the rest, if I type anything after the `[part1]` it won't work anymore. So it would be like from the end but between `-` and `[`

Comment: Please note my updated answer. If that doesn't match your requirement, please provide a list of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: The problem now is that if I have any `-` before in any point of my string it will start matching after that, but I wanted to match from the last `-` only, that is why I was using the `$`.